# Built-in, indexless, pretty-columns output with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pretty-print

I frequently find myself writing code like this to get nicely formatted multi-column output (without the index) when debugging or studying my data in pandas:

```
   dfs = dfs[dfs['some_id'] == the_id]
    cols = [
      'some_col',
      'another_col',
      'yet_another',
    ]

    print("\t".join(cols))
    for row in dfs[cols].values:
      print("\t\t".join([str(val) for val in row]))
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if there's a built in way to get this sort of output with a pandas function or direct lookup syntax. Sample output:

```
some_col    another_col    yet_another
a           b              c
x           y              z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call [`df.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html#pandas-dataframe-to-string) with the parameter `index=False`.

```
dfs = dfs[dfs['some_id'] == the_id]
    cols = [
      'some_col',
      'another_col',
      'yet_another',
    ]

print(dfs[cols].to_string(index=False))
```

---

MCVE:

```
print(df)

          0         1
0  0.335232 -1.256177
1 -1.367855  0.746646
2  0.027753 -1.176076
3  0.230930 -0.679613
4  1.261967  0.570967

print(df.to_string(index=False, col_space=10))

0          1
 0.335232  -1.256177
-1.367855   0.746646
 0.027753  -1.176076
 0.230930  -0.679613
 1.261967   0.570967
```

Comment: I usually use that to see all or a single column. How can I use that to select a subset of the total columns?

Comment: @JB Added the edit for your particular code at the top.